# Can't lauch .jar with windows scheduled task

Tags: java, jar, scheduled-tasks, windows-10

I've create a Jar file with eclipse, and I want it to be launch each day at a specific time, when I double click on it, it work fine, but when I try to launch it with the windows "scheduled task", it do nothing.
I've try many things in the scheduled task like "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\javaw.exe" with option : "-jar C:....\Myjar.jar" or also a .bat file which throw my jar, but same result ...

Comment: is the path C:....\Myjar.jar in a profile folder? If yes, the scheduled task must specify user name / password to see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have Java added to your path running this on the command line:

```
java -version
```

It should say something like:

```
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build ...)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build ...)
```

If it doesn't, add java to your path environment variable.

Once this is done, it should be as easy as doing:

```
java -jar C:\path\to\your\app.jar
```

Comment: 'your path' = the user-specific or system-wide Path environment variable

Comment: hi, I've done that already.
when I check my current process I can see one java application running but nothing  happened ...

Comment: @Alann what do you mean nothing happened? If the java process is running it means the application was launched. You should implement some logging (e.g. to a file) to see what is going on.

Comment: @mjn I think both should work, but I usually use the system path. If you use the user's path, make sure to configure the task to be launched from that specific user (obviously hehe).